# moving items up and down in a gridview in extjs 4.0

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a requirement to be able reorder the contents of a grid view. ie so the user can reshuffle the order of items. Are there any 4.0 implementations of this available. I was surprised the default examples don't appear to have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133637-Reorder-Grid-with-Drag-and-Drop) is an example of how this was implemented successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use my Code:

```
columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 50,
            menuDisabled:true,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            renderer: function(a,css,row,d,f,d){},
            items: [
            {
                iconCls: 'up-icon',
                tooltip: 'Move UP',
                handler: function(grid,index,c,d,f,row){
                    if(index < 1) return;
                    var id = row.data.id;
                    index--;
                    grid.store.remove(row, true);
                    grid.getStore().insert(index, row);
                }
            },
            '->',
            {
                iconCls: 'down-icon',
                tooltip: 'Move Down',
                handler: function(grid,index,c,d,f,row)
                {
                    if(index >= grid.all.endIndex)  return;
                    index++;
                    grid.store.remove(row, true);
                    grid.getStore().insert(index, row);
                }
            }
            ]
        },
...
]
```